# ¿Cómo actualizar mediante tabla temporal en MySQL varios registros?

Tags: mysql

Mi pregunta es cómo hacer un correcto Update con dos tablas en mi caso mi tabla principal el productos y la secundaria Temp donde tengo el ID  y el nuevo dato para la tabla principal. 
Al hacer mi Update me tira error y no sé porque.
Gracias de antemano por su tiempo y ayuda.

Intente hacer una tabla temporal donde guardo los IdProductos es PRIMARY KEY para el WHERE O JOIN Ya intente dos opciones: Solo en JOIN y me dice que especifique en el WHERE Y si coloco en WHERE con IN me dice que la tabla no se puede especificar. Gracias por la ayuda

**Consulta:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Temp AS
SELECT IdProductos, ((Existencia - Reserva) + Reserva) AS ReservaEdit  
from productos 
WHERE Upc='0000000000006' ;

UPDATE productos 
 INNER JOIN Temp
    on Temp.IdProductos = productos.IdProductos
    SET productos.Reserva = Temp.ReservaEdit
         WHERE productos.IdProductos IN (SELECT Temp.IdProductos FROM Temp);
```

Comment: Al menos a primera vista te puedo decir que la cláusula `IN` está de más. Ya está implícita en el join. Segundo, `(Existencia - Reserva) + Reserva` siempre es igual a `Existencia` por lo que tu update se podría hacer como  `UPDATE productos set reserva = existencia WHERE upc = '0000000000006';`

Comment: Agrega el texto del error a la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Gracias ya resolví mi problema ‘El código estaba bien tenía que arreglar unas especificaciones en mi editor para que funcione trabaje en MySQL Workbench.